# Go to second viewController without segues

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue

In the following code I have an action/button that when tapped takes you to a different viewController (`SecondViewController`), everything works fine but there is a line of code that I don't fully understand.

What is this line of code doing?

> secondVC.delegate = self

What delegate are we talking about here? Is that really needed if I only need to go to other view and I'm not passing any data?

```
@IBAction func goToView(sender: AnyObject) {  
    let secondVC= storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! SecondViewController  
    secondVC.delegate = self // is this needed?  
    self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated:true, completion:nil)  
}
```

Comment: Did you create custom delegate in second view controller?

Comment: Just to move to SecondViewController that line of code is not required. If you have implemented the delegate methods in your class and needs to be called from secondViewController then you need to set

Comment: There must be protocols in your presentViewController that should be called from secondViewController.Disabling secondVC.delegate = self doesnt harm if protocols are not used

Comment: Makes sense, if I understand this correctly this is only needed if using the delegations pattern to pass data around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. secondVC.delegate = self

This line of coding is passing object reference of current class in which you are standing to SecondViewController. Now, you can call methods of firstViewController(I assume this name), by using delegate object in secondViewController.

> 2. This delegate is not needed

, if you simply want to go to Next Screen which is SecondViewController in your case.

> 3. Helpful code:

Following will pass you to next controller, make sure that you have navigationController or not. As in NavigationController, you have to pushViewController into stack.

```
@IBAction func goToView(sender: AnyObject) {  
    let secondVC= storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! SecondViewController  
    self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

or in case of NavigationController

```
@IBAction func goToView(sender: AnyObject) {  

let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as? SecondViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC!, animated: true)
}
```

I hope my descriptive answer will help you. Feel free to ask any query in comments.

Thanks.

Comment: @ Veer Suthar - Got it. Now, let me make sure I understand this line `IF` used with the delegation pattern to pass data around. In plain english, is it right to say that this line of code is saying `I will be the delegate of the secondViewController` when used with delegation?

Comment: Delegation, we sent to other countries, to represent our country, similarly, Delegation means passing your own object, or representer to other controller so he can represent you and call you methods and variables. @fs_tigre

Comment: Like Delegation of United States(Country), in UNO(Organisation), so here, whatever that delegate will in UNO, will be words or acts of United States(Country). 

Here, FirstViewController is USA, while SecondViewController is UNO, inside secondViewController, you can handle methods of FirstViewControllers, using that delegate.

Comment: @ Veer Suthar - Hmm, so can I say that FirstViewController is saying `I, FirstViewController will be the delegate and will receive and pass around any message from the delegator SecondViewController`? Sorry if I deviated from my original question but this is also something I need to understand.

Comment: Yes, exactly, delete = object reference of firstviewcontroller dear.

Comment: You are Welcome! @fs_tigre

Answer (score 1):

Delete

> secondVC.delegate = self

and use it clear ;

```
@IBAction func goToView(sender: AnyObject) {  
    let secondVC =  storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! SecondViewController   
    self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated:true, completion:nil)  
}
```

Dont need to use delegate vc.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your situation I'd just use the following code:

```
@IBAction func goToView(sender: AnyObject)
{
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: This uses segues and I don't want to use segues on this case. Thanks.